# Working with Virtualenv Environment configured in IDEA's Python SDK

Tags: python, intellij-idea, virtualenv, intellij-plugin, virtual-environment

I have a Java project which I wish to export as a jar. What causes me the problem is the fact I'm calling a few Python scripts from inside the program, and those scripts require a few Python packages installed.
My call to the python script looks like:

```
root = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
cmd = "python " + root + "/my_script.py"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

And when I run the jar this works fine as long as I have the Python scripts in place, and all the Python packages (plus Python itself) installed on my computer (globally).

What I'd like to do though is to bundle all this Python stuff into my jar - so that I can run the app on any machine (the only requirement being Java 8 - no Python or any of its packages). I found out that **virtualenv** is exactly what would do the job here.

As I'm working in IDEA, I decided to configure virtualenv the SDK way, and so created a Virtualenv Environment following [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-virtual-environment.html). Added the packages I need in the environment's settings, placed my_script.py in the scripts directory. Ended up with a structure like this:

```
/
├── src
│   └── main.java
│   └── sample.fxml
└── venv
    ├── include
    │   
    ├── scripts [a bunch of default scripts here + my_script.py]
    └── lib  
          └── site-packages [a bunch of libraries here including the ones I require]   
          └── tcl8.6
```

I should say Jetbrain's tutorial really needs a continuation as I am absolutely lost from here. I just don't know how to reference my_script.py so that it uses the packages from venv rather than the global ones.

I would really appreciate your help or hints here!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion venv would be not your definitive solution:
If you need to use your java code on different Hosts ( Windows , linux, MACOS ) you should recompile a venv for every different machine and this is not your case.
Maybe a solution would be "Freeze" you python code.
Have a lot of interesting articles about code Freezing in Python, my preferred is [python-guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/).

So, afeter code Freezing, you can start the python code from java like an executable and you can provide different executables depending on OS.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual environment still requires Python to be installed, it just allows you to choose which of the installed python interpreters to use, and it allows you to install a set of packages.

If you really don't want to depend on Python being installed, you might be able to use [Jython](https://www.jython.org/). It runs Python code on the JVM. However, it only supports Python 2.7. Python 3 support is being [worked on](https://github.com/jython/jython3), but slowly.

None of this is going to be easy if you have a lot of package dependencies.